背景画像の上に要素を並べたい
header部分の背景画像の上に<h1>の要素と<ul>の要素を配置したいのですが、position:relative;をbg-imgに適用し、position:absolute;を背景画像上に置きたい<h1>や<ul>要素に適用したのですが反映されません。どうしたら良いでしょうか？下記がheader部分のHTMLとCSSのコードです。よろしくお願いします
HTML
<body>
    <div class="bg-img"></div>
    <header>
        <h1><img src="img/logo.svg" alt=""></h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li id="#menu">MENU</li>
                <li id="about">ABOUT</li>
                <li id="location">LOCATION</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

CSS
.header {
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h2 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
}


ul {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    color: white;
    gap: 30px;
    font-size: 1em;
    position: absolute;
}

.bg-img {
    background-image: url(../img/mainvisual.jpg);
    background-image: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.logo img {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0%;
    right: 0;
    color: white;
}

.headerlist li {
    font-size: 20px;
}


bg-imgにrelativeを適応すると、子要素に指定したabsoluteが
bg-imgの位置を元に浮くので、bg-imgの中にheaderを入れることになる
と思います。
その後、headerにabdoluteを適応し(クラスじゃないので.いらないです)・・・
などといった工程が必要になります。
それはとても美しくない書き方に見えますので、他のやり方を推奨します。
(bodyにbackground-img適応するとか？←正直コードから完成図が見えてこないのでやり方に関してはなんとも)
あとh1の中に画像入れないでください。余計にややこしくなっています。
(ただのブロック要素とみなして使っているなら何も言いませんが。)

ご指摘ありがとうございます、もう一度改めてコードレイアウト確認を自分でも行ってみます
